# Page not loading in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I just made some CSS changes to a page and all works perfect in firefox safari, chrome but when i view it in IE there is nothing. I mean just a blank page

http://posnation.com/pos_support/aldelo_training_dvd

Also this is a miva site

Comment: which ie? IE6, iE7, IE9?

Comment: It works fine for me (tested with IE6 and IE8). Try clearing your cache.

Comment: it wasnt working initially and after i closed the title tag all worked well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close title tag.

Answer (score 4):

try validating your html. You also don't have an end title tag.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the  tag in the page head isn't closed properly (line 4). FF and Chrome often fix this sort of error for you as they render the page, IE isn't on this occasion.

Comment: While your answer is correct, it doesn't add anything beyond what the two answers posted 15 minutes ago already said.